# Why the value of static variable won't increase?

Tags: c#, variables, static

Why the value of static variable showing use first account object won't change?
I mean in the following code, I created two object which will assign value to static variable `accountNumberSeed`, and I've checked that the static variable increased if I call it directly using `BankAccount.Number`, but if I call its value using the first object reference `account.Number`, the value of static won't increase even though I create object constructor to increase it.

```
class BankAccount
{
    public static int accountNumberSeed = 1234567890;
    public BankAccount(string name, decimal initialBalance)
    {
        this.Owner = name;
        this.Balance = initialBalance;
        //using constructor to assign value to static variable.
        this.Number = accountNumberSeed.ToString();
        accountNumberSeed++;
    }
}
```

This is another class which creates two object and reference static variable using first object.

```
var account = new BankAccount("rian", 1000);
var account2 = new BankAccount("asda", 1000);
Console.WriteLine(account.Number);// this will show 1234567890
Console.WriteLine(BankAccount.Number);// this will show 1234567891
```

Why the value is different? I think they both should show 1234567891?

Comment: What do you mean by "if i call it using the first object reference"? `account.accountNumberSeed` will give a syntax error.

Comment: sr,my fault, i mean call its value using account.Number

Comment: `BankAccount.Number` is going to cause a compilation error.  Did you mean `BankAccount.accountNumberSeed` or `account2.Number` instead?

Comment: i mean, account.Number , anyway ive figured out why, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks why the static variable isn't increasing. But it is increasing.

"why the value is different, i think it both show 1234567891"

This contradicts your initial question. The reason they don't both print 1234567891 is because the static variable gets incremented twice: once when the first object is instantiated, and again when the second one is.

Just in case you think the output should be 1234567891 and 1234567892, note that in that case the problem is you're assigning to your property...

```
 this.Number = accountNumberSeed.ToString();
```

...before you increment the static variable.

```
 accountNumberSeed++;
```

Comment: thank you ,i know the value increased , but my point is, before calling account.Number the value has already in creased to 1234567891,and then i call account.Number i think in this time it should return 1234567891 because increased value. where am i wrong? please help me.

Comment: @Xian the ++ doesn't happen until _after_ the assignment. At the end of this code, `accountNumberSeed` will be `1234567892`

Comment: "Console.WriteLine(account.Number)" should not return 1234567891 because you assigned accountNumberSeed.ToString() to it *before* accountNumberSeed++. Make sense?

Comment: yes,i know what you mean,but what make me confused is, after these two var account = new BankAccount("rian", 1000); var account2 = new BankAccount("asda", 1000); the number should be 1234567891,and then i use account.Number why is it not 1234567891

Comment: after that two lines of creating objects, the value of Number should be 1234567891, but when i use account.Number its value is 1234567890, so it means that only first constructor worked. i dont know why.

Comment: oh,i know why, cause property  Number just belong to its own object ,and i assign the static value to it, so property Number value should be different for different object.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `static` keyword makes the variable `accountNumberSeed` one for the whole program, i.e. whenever you call `BankAccount`, it remains the same variable in the memory. Hence, when you call it the first time, it has the value of 1234567890, pass it to `Number`, which you printed first, then incremented to 1234567891. The second time you call `BankAccount`, the same procedure happens, starta with 1234567890, pass, then 1234567891, but this time you printed `BankAccount.Number` which is already 1234567891. Try doing it more times, and I believe you will get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it increment is "The class loader loads the static fields(variable or methods) only once while initializing the class. static fields are not depends on object at all. For detail understanding, put a break point on two object creations and on static variable then run the code.

For first object creation,
 "public static int accountNumberSeed = 1234567890;"  //will execute.

For second object creation,
 "public static int accountNumberSeed = 1234567890;"  //will not execute.

For ur information:

=>It is a variable which belongs to the class and not to object(instance)

=>Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution. These variables will be initialized first, before the initialization of any instance variables

=>A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class

=>A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object.

Thankyou